# How to use function at Vue local component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

at my example js code is:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [1,2,3]
  },
  methods: {
    change: function(number) {
      return number === 2 ? 'a' : 'b';
    }
  },
  components: {
    'html-list': {
      props: ['item'],
      template: '<li :title='change(item)'> text </li>'
    }
  }
});
```

at my example html code is:

```
<ul id='app'>
  <html-list
    v-for:'num in list'
    :item='num'
  ></html-list>
</ul>
```

I want the following result:

```
<ul id='app'>
  <li title='b'> text </li>
  <li title='a'> text </li>
  <li title='b'> text </li>
</ul>
```

But it's not working.

I tried several different ways but couldn't find a way to dynamically bind data by calling a function on the component.

I don't want to use global components because there are so many components to create.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to use function `change`, which is not declared in component.

There are several solutions for this:

1. declare function in component

```js
components: {
  'my-component': {
    props: [...],
    template: '...',
    methods: {
      change: function() {...}
    }
  }
}
```

2. if you want use function from parent component `template: '<li :title='$parent.change(item)'> text </li>'`
3. Use Vuex